# Apache Camel WebDav file download

Tags: java, apache-camel

Is there a way to download files from a WebDav URL to local directory using apache camel?
Since, https://github.com/Giwi/camel-dav/wiki is not updated for a long time i am a bit skeptical to use it.
Is there any other way i can access the folder structure and download files after filtering?

Answer (score 0):

I also found [simasch's solution](https://github.com/simasch/camel-webdav), but 3 years of inactivity...

And only contains a Producer, no Consumer (although "coming soon" ;-)), so not for your purpose, but may be a good starting point to extend with a Consumer.